# Почему после вызова learningDays мне выводится 3, хотя в конструкторе я указал для него значение 12?

Tags: c++, классы, getter

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

int giveRandomRating(int lesson[], int numberOfRatings )
{
    /*
    numberOfRatings-количесвто оценок
    Даёт определенное количесвто рандомных оценок для определенного предмета
    */
    for (int i = 0; i<=numberOfRatings-1; i++)
    {
        lesson[i]=rand()%5 + 1;
    }
}


bool find_lesson(string lessons[],string nameLesson, int amount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<=amount-1; i++)
    {
        if (lessons[i] == nameLesson)
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}



class Human
{
public:
private:
    string name;
    int age;

public:
    Human(string given_name, int given_age)
    {
        this-> name = given_name;
        this -> age = given_age;
    }
    string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    void SetName(string given_name)
    {
        name = given_name;
    }

    int GetAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    void SetAge( int given_age)
    {
        age = given_age;
    }

};


class Student: public Human
{
private:
    int days;
    int math[];
    int numberOflessons;
    int learningDays;

public:

    Student(string name, int age,string lessons[],int numberOflessons, int learningDays):Human(name,age)
    {
        /*numberOflesson-общее количество предметов, которые есть у ученика
          learningDays-влияет на количесвто оценок по предметам(если будут 5 дней, то по математике, литературе, физике и т.д и по каждому из предметов будет 5 оценок)
        */

        name = name;
        age = age;
        numberOflessons = numberOflessons;
        learningDays = learningDays;

        if (find_lesson(lessons,"math",numberOflessons)==true)
        {
            giveRandomRating(math,learningDays);
        }

    }

    getMath()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<=learningDays - 1; i++)
        {
            cout << math[i]<<" ";
        }
    }

    getLearningDay()
    {
        //Выводит learningDays
        cout <<learningDays;
    }


};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string lessons[5] = {"russian","math","litra","phys","izo"};

    Student alyx("Alyx",15,lessons,5,12);
    alyx.getLearningDay();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На каком языке это написано? Что это за функции без типа возвращаемого значения в классе `Student`? Что это за `int math[];`? О каком "выводится 3" может идти речь? В С++ это невозможно даже скомпилировать.

Answer (score 2):

Вы понимаете, что делаете здесь?

```
Student(string name, int age,string lessons[],int numberOflessons,
        int learningDays):Human(name,age)
{
    name = name;
    age = age;
    numberOflessons = numberOflessons;
    learningDays = learningDays;
```

Вы аргументы конструктора присваиваете сами себе!

Правильнее

```
Student(string name, int age,string lessons[],int numberOflessons,
        int learningDays):Human(name,age)
{
    this->numberOflessons = numberOflessons;
    this->learningDays = learningDays;
```

Еще правильнее:

```
Student(string name, int age,string lessons[],int numberOflessons,
        int learningDays):Human(name,age),numberOflessons(numberOflessons),learningDays(learningDays)
{
```

Увы, это далеко не все ваши ошибки. Например, в `giveRandomRating(math,learningDays);` вы портите память - и получаете UB. У вас массив `math` *нулевой длины* - так куда вы пишете информацию? В какие-то места в памяти рядом, вот и запарываете другие поля. Хотите убедиться? Закомментируйте этот вызов в конструкторе и попробуйте снова...

Comment: Я сделал как вы сказали, но при вызове getLearningDay мне выводит цифру 3, а  не 12

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.